# how can I delete videos stored in documents folder?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have stored the videos in the documents folder. the path is

```
/Users/sridhar/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/EC177E77-8665-485C-93DE-62350FA6D0E7/Documents/air.mp4
```

I want to delete the video . How can I do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"air.mp4"];
BOOL succeed = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
```

Comment: You don't have to make two strings, do you? Can't you just use this when getting the path?
`NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: Yes you can. The variant you choose I think depends on what level of readability you want to get... It may be useful to see each step just for learning purposes

Comment: Thank You Vladimir. It's was working fine. Thank you for posting the code in more readability.